# A line starting with a space

Tags: spacing, tex-core

Consider the following Plain TeX manuscript.

```
. .%
\par%
{ }.%
\end
```

This typesets

> . .
>   .

The space on the third manuscript line is not ignored by the tokenizer. So why isn't there a space at the beginning of the second typeset line?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `\def` etc. Just type a `.tex` file where a paragraph starts with a bunch of spaces before `hello`, and see what you get with and without those spaces. :-)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: There's a difference. In your example the opening spaces are ignored by the tokenizer and never passed on to the "stomach". In my example the space isn't ignored by the tokenizer, and is passed on to the stomach.

Comment: Ok, try with `{ } hello` then :-)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Yes, this is a good example. I've replaced my example with yours. So why does it happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An opening brace does not start a paragraph, so the space in encountered while TeX is still in vertical mode where spaces are simply ignored.  Try switching to horizontal mode.

```
. .%
\par%
\leavevmode{ }.%
\end
```

[image]

Comment: the example would be even more striking if you omitted the `%` signs and put the `{ }` on a new line.